# Why is console.log statements not appearing in my FireBug console anymore?

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug, firefox3.6, firebug1.5

I'm using FF 3.6 and FireBug 1.5.0

my console.log statements are no longer appearing in my firebug console. is anyone else experiencing this? is there a setting somewhere that got switched that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the javascript you are debugging tries to write something to the console variable. As an example, I stuck the following code into a random javascript file:

console = {};
console.log('asdfasdf');

After trying to set console to an empty object, console.log didn't do anything.

To fix this, you should only need to figure out where your script is trying to change the console variable, and then refresh the page.